# AWS rugy gem seems to be failing on heroku and locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-web-services, bundler

Anyonw have any idea what's happening with the aws-sdk gem. I noticed this popped up in one of my applications today and it's effecting more then one now. I get the same error in all app's yet the link to the gem seems to be working.

On Heroku

```
   Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Not Found 404 (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-1.19.0.gem)
   An error occurred while installing aws-sdk (1.19.0), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install aws-sdk -v '1.19.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

!
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

And locally:

$ gem install aws-sdk
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found 404 (http://production.cf.rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-1.19.0.gem)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently I'm not the only one - the file seems to have gone AWOL from s3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a botched deploy of some kind, version 1.18.0 looks like it's available.  1.19.0 was released today, do you really need to be using that version?  Did you do a bundle update across your whole application or something that may have forced all gems to update?  Don't do that! :)

Might want to let them know: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby